# sabre/dav - The server specified an invalid calendar home

Tags: symfony, caldav, mitmproxy, sabredav

I'm working on including sabre/dav as base for a CalDAV-Server into an existing symfony-project. Until now I've successfully extened the auth-classes. It's possible to log in with Lightning and, using the calendars and principals backend from sabre/caldav to work with a single calendar. The same applies when interacting with the system via browser.

Now I'm trying to use iCal (9.0) on macOS (10.12.5). Authentication seems to work fine, but afterwards I'm stuck with an

**"The server specified an invalid calendar home."**

error.

I tried to look into it with mitmproxy, but somehow the messages from iCal to my websystem (running on http://localhost:8080) are not being logged. mitmrpoxy is running on 8081, and all other connection (including a webcal-call from iCal) are logged.
I also tried Charles, but somehow the messages from iCal seem to lose the port 8080 when tha proxy is used (via localhost.charlesproxy.com).

I have also enabled the debug-console in iCal and see the entries in the Console-app, but until now, there is no info that get my any further.

What would be the next piece of information I'd most likely would need to get - and what tool might help me?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I think you should focus on getting Charles working first. Maybe not using localhost but the en0 IP address of your machine is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. By now I got Baikal up and running, and I'm getting the same "The server specified an invalid calendar home."-error when trying to load the calendars with iCal. Working on them via Lightning works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my error. I was trying to access the calendars via

http://localhost/caldav/

... thinking that iCal would add the needed paths to /calendars, /principals, ... by itself.

Turns out, I had to use

http://localhost/caldav/principals/USERNAME

to configure the account in iCal.